# iOS Media Player Thumbnail and M3U8

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, m3u8, airplay, hls.js

I like to know what I need to do to my m3u8 web video to present a thumbnail within the iOS player like the one attached. So far, I only get to see the web site‘s fav icon. The webpage also has an og:image and and the video tag has a poster image. This example shows my m3u8 video embedded in an html video tag:

[image: icon]

My m3u8 playlist only contains videos. I tried the video tag‘s poster attribute, but that did not affect the player.

I would like to see something related to the video content like this:

[image: example]

Comment: HLS Authoring Specification for Apple Devices: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices

Comment: I read this document before, but I couldnt find anything about a cover / thumbnail picture. iOS does not produce it automatically.

Comment: Is the screenshot in your example from a stream within an iOS application, or a stream from a website. This is possible through metadata fields on AVPlayer. Not sure how to accomplish from the web only.

Comment: @DanielStorm the video is embedded in an html video tag. Which was presented within a WKWebView.